# Data alignment vs. cache locality

Tags: java, android, caching, memory-access

From memory, data may only be read in the natural word size of the architecture. For example, on a 32-bit system, data is read from memory in 4-byte chunks. If a 2-byte or 1-byte value is added to memory, their reading will still require accessing a 4-byte word. (In case of the 2-byte value, two 4-byte accesses might be required, if the value was stored on a word boundary.)

Therefore, an access to an individual value is the fastest when it requires accessing a single word, and minimal additional work (such as masking) is required. If I'm correct, this is the reason virtual machines (such as *JVM* or *Android's Dalvik*) lay out member variables in 4-byte boundaries in `Object` instances.

Another concept is cache friendliness, i.e. locality (e.g. L1, L2). If many values must be traversed/processed directly after each other, it is beneficial that they are stored close to each other (ideally, in a contiguous block). This is spatial locality. If this isn't possible, at least the operations on the same value should be done in the same time period (temporal locality -- i.e. it has a high chance that the value is retained in cache while the operations are performed on it).

As far as I can see, the above two concepts can be "contradictory" in some cases, and the choice between them depends on their usage scenario. For example, a smaller amount of contiguous data is more cache friendly than a greater amount (trivial), yet if random access is commonly required on some data, the word-aligned (but greater-sized) structure might be beneficial -- **unless** the whole structure fits in the cache. Therefore, whether locality (~arrays) or alignment benefits should be preferred depends on *how the values will be manipulated*, I think.

There is a scenario which is interesting for me: let's assume a pathfinding algorithm which receives the input graph (*and* other auxiliary structures) as arrays. (Most of its input arrays store values that are <= 32767.)

The pathfinding algorithm performs very many **random** accesses on the arrays (in several loops). In this sense, an `int[]` might be desired for input data (on Android/ARM), because the values will be on word boundary when accessed. (On the other hand, if sequential traversals were needed, then a smaller datatype would be recommended -- especially for large arrays -- because of a higher probability of cache-friendliness.)

However, what if the (randomly accessed) input data would fit L1/L2 if specified as a `short[]`, but not fit if specified as `int[]`? In such a case, would the advantage of 4-byte alignment of `int[]` for random access be outweighted by the cache-friendliness of `short[]`?

In a concrete application, of course, I'd make measurements for comparison. That wouldn't necessarily answer the above questions, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can assure that moving to short leads to a significatn better locality (aka everything is in cache), this outweights alignment penalties.

access to cache is in the low nanos <10ns, access to ram is 60-80ns